# When $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|<\infty,$ does $\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k e^{ikx } \right)^n dx=0$ hold?

Tags: calculus, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $a=\{a_k\}_{k=1}^\infty \subset \mathbb C$ satisfy $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k|<\infty.$

Then, does $$\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k e^{ikx } \right)^n dx=0\ \mathrm {for}\ n\in \mathbb N$$ hold ?

I know

(i) $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ikx}dx=0$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$

(ii) For $\{f_k\}_{k=1}^\infty \subset L^1$, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int |f_k(x)| dx<\infty \Rightarrow \sum \int f_k (x) dx=\int \sum f_k (x)dx.$

---

I tried to prove by induction.

The case $n=1$.

$\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k e^{ikx }  dx=
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^{2\pi} a_k e^{ikx }  dx
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \int_0^{2\pi}e^{ikx }  dx
=0.$

(The change of $\sum$ and $\int$ is justified by
$\sum_k \int_{0}^{2\pi}|a_k e^{ikx }|dx=\sum_k \int_{0}^{2\pi}|a_k|dx=2\pi \sum_k |a_k|<\infty.)$

Suppose the case $n-1$ holds.

Then,
\begin{align*}
&\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k e^{ikx} \right)^n dx\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k e^{ikx} \right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k e^{ikx} \right)^{n-1} dx \\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{k_1=1}^\infty \left[a_{k_1} e^{ik_{1}x}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k e^{ikx} \right)^{n-1} \right]dx \cdots (\ast)
\end{align*}

Now, check that we can change $\sum$ and $\int.$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k_1=1}^\infty \int_0^{2\pi} \left|a_{k_1} e^{ik_{1}x}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k e^{ikx} \right)^{n-1} \right|dx\\
&=\sum_{k_1=1}^\infty|a_{k_1}|
\int_0^{2\pi}
\left|\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k e^{ikx} \right|^{n-1}dx\\
&\leqq 
\sum_{k_1=1}^\infty|a_{k_1}|
\cdot 
\int_0^{2\pi}
\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k | \right)^{n-1}dx
\\
&=2\pi \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty |a_k | \right)^{n}\\
&<\infty
\end{align}

Thus,
$$(\ast)=
\sum_{k_1=1}^\infty \int_0^{2\pi}\left[a_{k_1} e^{ik_{1}x}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k e^{ikx} \right)^{n-1} \right]dx \\
=\sum_{k_1=1}^\infty a_{k_1} \int_0^{2\pi}e^{ik_{1}x}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k e^{ikx} \right)^{n-1} dx 
.$$

How can I use the supposition the case $n-1$ : $\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k e^{ikx} \right)^{n-1} dx=0 $ ?

I don't think I can use this supposition for $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ik_{1}x}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k e^{ikx} \right)^{n-1} dx 
$ directly.

$\int_0^{2\pi} F(x) dx=0$ does not necessarily imply $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ikx}F(x)dx=0$ for $k\in \mathbb N.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $\displaystyle\max_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|F_{k_1,\ldots,k_n}(x)|\leq M_{k_1,\ldots,k_n}$ and that $\displaystyle\sum_{k_1,\ldots,k_n} M_{k_1,\ldots,k_n}<\infty$.

Then $\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\sum_{k_1,\ldots,k_n}F_{k_1,\ldots,k_n}(x)\,\text{d}x=\sum_{k_1,\ldots,k_n}\int_0^{2\pi}F_{k_1,\ldots,k_n}(x)\,\text{d}x$.

Therefore, you just need to check that the expansion of $\displaystyle\left(\sum_k a_k\right)^n$ is an absolutely convergent sum.

Comment: Can I see about this theorem somewhere ? @Chris_Sanders

Comment: @SABAR the dominated convergence theorem should suffice for this

Comment: @SABAR https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4185733/interchanging-integral-and-sum-in-case-of-absolute-and-uniform-convergence

Comment: not hard to adapt the stuff in the link, once you understand it, to what I wrote in this answer